# How to make forward button in the jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

In this example we manage to make the back button work but the forward button seems to be a problem: when it's pressed it doesn't work.

This is the footer bar code:

```
<div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
        <ul>
           <li>
               <a data-rel="back" data-icon="back" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a data-rel="forward" data-icon="forward" data-direction="forward">Fwd</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div><!-- Mobile Footer -->
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).on("navigate", function(event, data) {
    alert(data.state.url);
});
```

In the browser, if I click the back and forward buttons, then I can see the alert message for both buttons.

In the jQuery Mobile page I can see the alert message when I click the back button. But I can't see the alert message when I click the forward button.

Can you check the above code and let me know how can I make the forward button work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `forward` button doesn't work because `data-rel="forward"` does not exist in jQuery Mobile (you can check the docs for `data-rel` [here](https://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/)).

You can however simulate the browser forward button adding this feature yourself:

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-rel=forward]", function()
{
    window.history.forward();
});
```